# Why use an IIFE in this situation?

Tags: javascript, iife

In [an article on browser plugin development](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/browser-extension-edge-chrome-firefox-opera-brave-vivaldi/), they use this code:

```
window.browser = (function () {
  return window.msBrowser ||
    window.browser ||
    window.chrome;
})();
```

Why would they use an IIFE rather than, say:

```
window.browser = window.msBrowser || window.browser || window.chrome;
```

Is there something that an IIFE brings to the table that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no advantage to it in that specific situation. Perhaps the code you're looking at originally had more logic which was subsequently removed.